# Ruby Ranges, why is a decimal included in exclusive range?

Tags: ruby

```
case something
  when 0...10
    puts 'success'
  else
    puts 'fail'
end
```

If I enter 9.5, the output is 'success'. As I understand, ... means 10 won't be included, so it counts from 0 to 9? What's going on here? Also, the book with this example (I modified it ofc not to copy the code) recommended to use exclusive ranges in case statements, is this considered a best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0...10` means that `10` isn't included in range. But it also mean that everything less than `10` (but greater than `0`) is included.

Using `...` instead of `..` doesn't change the end of the range:

```
(0..10).end
# => 10
(0...10).end
# => 10
```

It modifies inclusion of end in this range:

```
(0..10).exclude_end?
# => false
(0...10).exclude_end?
# => true
```

More info about ranges in Ruby here:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Range.html